# GUI controls validation pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, frontend

I am struggling to find a suitable or elegant way of handling validations in server side code.
Currently I am using asp.net website, however I would love to have a pattern that can be equally applicable to MVC also.

I am posting a sample / psuedo code purely for describing the problem, the actual code differs a lot and is extremely complex:

markup code looks like:

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>Item1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Item2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Item3</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList2" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>Item4</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Item5</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Item6</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" />
```

code behind looks like:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ValidatePage()) {
        //call business layer and do some operation.
    }
}

bool ValidatePage()
{
    int visibility = GetVisibility();
    switch (visibility)
    {
        case 0: //TextBox1.Text can not be empty
        //in case it is found to be empty then return false and print the message in web page
        case 1: //TextBox1.Text can not be empty
        //in case it is found to be empty then return false and print the message in web page
        case 2: // both of textbox1 and textbox2 should not be empty
        //in case they are found to be empty then return false and print the message in web page

    }
    //return true or false as per the above validations
}
int GetVisibility()
{
    //if page is redirected from page1 then return 1
    //if page is redirected from page2 then return 2
    //if page is directly open from homepage then return 0
    return 0;
}
```

---

1. Problem is Validation becomes complicated as more of check boxes are
   checked(in other words more contexts are looked).
2. I am thinking it of
       making as a God method that will provide all validations no matter
       which ever button in the page is calling it (I am open to any
       suggestions/criticism on this approach).
3. Page is made from scratch and new features/controls/validations are
   frequently added.

**Note:**

I am aware of Requiredfield validators and due to some complexities I am avoiding it here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a class that contains references to the related controls, along with a `Validate()` method (which can be implemented in a subclass or passed in as a lambda). Then I'd just keep the instances in a collection which I'd iterate to call each `Validate()`.